# Как правильно делать относительно момента открытия/закрытия соединения, если в программе используется БД?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Как правильно делать относительно момента открытия/закрытия соединения, если в программе используется БД:

1. открыть соединение, например при запуске программы, работать с БД, выполняя различные действия с ней, перед закрытием программы закрыть соединение и закрыть программу

или

2. запустить программу, далее при необходимости, например, записи в БД, открыть соединение, осуществить запись, закрыть соединение, далее этот процесс (открытие соединения-операция-закрытие) повторять при необходимости

?

Comment: Обычно делают 1

Answer (score 0):

если однопоточное приложение - то вариант 1
если многопоточное/многопроцессное - то вариант 2